# Cannot create table in the newly created DB from Visual Studio SSDT SSIS Package with error "Failed to Connect to source using connection manager"

Tags: sql, database, ssis, connection

Steps to reproduce:
1. On my SSIS package, I have Flat File src -> OLE DB Destination to create new DB with new table from the Mapping départements.csv file
***I cannot upload file in stackoverflow*** This is what it looks like:

[image: CSVFile]

2. I already loaded properly the CSV file in the Flat File src
   [image: FlatFileOLEDST]
3. On OLE DB Destination, I create a new connection

[image: OLE DB New DB Connection]

4. I specify Server name as localhost then specify name of the table below. As I use SQL Developer version, so localhost is ok. I already did this in class for another DB and it worked fine

[image]

5. Click new to create table

[image: CreateTable]

6. Here I get a warning but might not be related

[image: Warning]

7. Modify create table script

[image: CreateTableScript]

8. After click ok, I get this error:

   ### "TITLE: Microsoft Visual Studio

The table cannot be created.

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Failed to connect to the source using the connection manager 'localhost.CrimeInFrance_STA' (Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Design)

---

BUTTONS:

### OK

"

[image: TablecannotBeCreated]

9. More error details:

[image: ErrDetail1]

[image: ErrDetail2]

The csv file that I used is attached. It seems I cannot connected to the newly created DB? But I did the same thing in the classes for other DBs in my SQL Server Management Studio and I've never got an error like this:

[image: SQLServerMgnStudio]

Could someone please help me on this? This seems to be something so simple but I don't know what goes wrong. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Need to create DB in the SQL management studio first before doing this.